# Calling 2 different divs using onclick() in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I would like to know how to call two different divs using a single Onclick() function in JavaScript.

I have two divs and a button (Right now I have 2 buttons each for a single div). whenever these buttons are pressed then the 2 divs need to execute. I just don't know how to call two divs at a time.

Here is the sample code.

```
<div id="scroll" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>
<input type="button" name="" value="Scroll" onclick="zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll');" />
<div id="scroll2" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>
<input type="button" name="" value="Scroll" onclick="zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll2');" />
```

How to control these two divs by using a single Onclick Event? Am using two Onclick Events but I need to have only single onclick which calls both the div's.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to trigger `zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll');` and `zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll2');` together when you click on something? Why not put these two sentences into one onclick function?

Comment: You can trigger Scroll for scroll and scroll2, but let's make this somehow generic. Please post the .Scroll function so we can help you. Basically you can place a class for each div like `<div id="scroll" class="js-clickable-scroll" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>` and  `<div id="scroll2" class="js-clickable-scroll" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>` and then trigger the scroll for elements with `js-clickable-scroll` class.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked well.. Thanks

Comment: And after that you can create another div with this class `js-clickable-scroll` and it will work for the 3rd too as you trigger for all elements with that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the function twice in the onclick attribute, once for the 'scroll' and once for 'scroll2':

```
<div id="scroll" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>
<div id="scroll2" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>
<input type="button" name="" value="Scroll" onclick="zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll'); zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll2');">
```

But you should not use onclick attribute and use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead like this:

```
<div id="scroll" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>
<div id="scroll2" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:40px;"></div>
<input type="button" name="" id="scrollerBtn" value="Scroll" />
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        var scrollerBtn = document.getElementById('scrollerBtn');
        scrollerBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
             zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll');
             zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll2');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Worked like a champ!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make a single function that handles both divs at the same time and have each button refer to this function?
Something like:

```
var handler = function( event ) {
    zxcTextScroller.Scroll(event.target.name);
};

<input type="button" name="scroll" value="Scroll" onclick="handler" />
<input type="button" name="scroll2" value="Scroll" onclick="handler" />
```

OR if you want the function to always scroll both divs:

```
var handler = function() {
    zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll');
    zxcTextScroller.Scroll('scroll2');
};
```